# How to submit form of multi steps via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to submit the form without refreshing the page, I use this library to do multistep form but, at the end it force to submit the form by loading to the form action, I tried to stop it by setting the form.submit to false, but when I did that It stop sending request vai ajax.

My multstepform.js

```
 (function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.multiStepForm = function(args) {
  if(args === null || typeof args !== 'object' || $.isArray(args))
    throw  " : Called with Invalid argument";
  var form = this;
  var tabs = form.find('.containerformtab');
  var steps = form.find('.stepform');
  steps.each(function(i, e){
    $(e).on('click', function(ev){
    });
  });
  form.navigateTo = function (i) {/*index*/
    /*Mark the current section with the class 'current'*/
    tabs.removeClass('currentform').eq(i).addClass('currentform');
    // Show only the navigation buttons that make sense for the current section:
    form.find('.previousform').toggle(i > 0);
    atTheEnd = i >= tabs.length - 1;
    form.find('.nextform').toggle(!atTheEnd);
    // console.log('atTheEnd='+atTheEnd);
    form.find('.submitform').toggle(atTheEnd);
    fixStepIndicator(curIndex());
    return form;
  }
  function curIndex() {
    /*Return the current index by looking at which section has the class 'current'*/
    return tabs.index(tabs.filter('.currentform'));
  }
  function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    steps.each(function(i, e){
      i == n ? $(e).addClass('activeform') : $(e).removeClass('activeform');
    });
  }
  /* Previous button is easy, just go back */
  form.find('.previousform').click(function() {
    form.navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
  });

  /* Next button goes forward iff current block validates */
  form.find('.nextform').click(function() {
    if('validations' in args && typeof args.validations === 'object' && !$.isArray(args.validations)){
      if(!('noValidate' in args) || (typeof args.noValidate === 'boolean' && !args.noValidate)){
        form.validate(args.validations);
        if(form.valid() == true){
          form.navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    form.navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
  });

  form.find('.submitform').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(typeof args.beforeSubmit !== 'undefined' && typeof args.beforeSubmit !== 'function')
      args.beforeSubmit(form, this);
    //check if args.submit is set false if not then form.submit is not gonna run, if not set then will run by default        
    if(typeof args.submit === 'undefined' || (typeof args.submit === true /*'boolean'*/ && args.submit)){
      form.submit();
    }
    return form;
  });

  /*By default navigate to the tab 0, if it is being set using defaultStep property*/
  typeof args.defaultStep === 'number' ? form.navigateTo(args.defaultStep) : null;

  form.noValidate = function() {

  }
  return form;
 };
 }( jQuery ));
```

my index.html

```
    <form action="<?= URL; ?>/Page/add" method="POST" id="myForm">
        <div class="containerformtab">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="containerformtab">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div style=" padding:10px;">
           <div style="float:left">
             <button type="button" class="submitform create-btn" id="insertchurch">CREATE</button>
              <button type="button" class="previousform previous_btn">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="nextform next_btn">Next</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

my custom.js

```
             $(function(){

     // validate password match
     $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", (value, element, arg)=>{
      return arg !== value;
     }, "Value must not equal arg.");


     var val = {
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
        },
        messages: {
        }
    }

   $("#myForm").multiStepForm({
            // submitHandler: function(form){},

            beforeSubmit: function(form,submit){
                insert();
                return false;
            }
    }).navigateTo(0); 
     })(jQuery);

    // ajax call
    // function to add church
    function insert()
    {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var url     = $('#myform').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : 'POST',
            data : { name: name },
            success : (response) =>{
                $('.message').html(response).show();
                $('#createChurch').trigger('reset');
            },
            error : (response) =>{

            }

   });
```

Comment: what happens if you just remove the action all together in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.submit` (or `.on`) to listen onto the `submit` JavaScript event.

Then `.preventDefault()` on the event to cancel the *default* behavior (of submitting the form)

```js
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: From line 54 to 67,                                                                                    form.find('.submitform').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(typeof args.beforeSubmit !== 'undefined' && typeof args.beforeSubmit !== 'function')
      args.beforeSubmit(form, this);
    //check if args.submit is set false if not then form.submit is not gonna run, if not set then will run by default        
    if(typeof args.submit === 'undefined' || (typeof args.submit === true /*'boolean'*/ && args.submit)){
      form.submit();
    }
    return form;
  });

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with there?

Comment: From that solution you recommended me help from preventing page to load but I tested the ajax url it seem to return undefined

Comment: i need to stop form from loading and use ajax to send data to the server, I tried to use submitHadler: and beforeSubmit methods but I did not succeed

Comment: First try manually loading the URL in the browser and confirm that the page is not blank. If it is giving something back, try console.log'ing the response in the ajax function. Make sure that the page is giving back 200 OK as well.

Comment: The status is OK on console, the submitform is a button that shown to the lash step and its event  when it clicked form the form to sumbit form.submit(), from the condition above the first comment I commented

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but are you sure `response` in the ajax is returning undefined?

Comment: yes, when I used $('#myForm').submit(e){}, I get undefinde on alert() that I put inside my insert() for ajax

Comment: Now I am getting the right url, I was wrong by putting #myForm as #myform to call the form attr

Comment: I didn't caught that mistake either, hahaha. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to fetch the data via ajax, I have php controller with add(), that fetch the data from model with PDO, the status was ok through I ajax but I am getting difficult to display data to the page